Relation between norms and inverse moduli of totally convex function
Let $f\colon \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable convex function. Its  Bregman divergence is defined as
$B_{f}(x,y) = f(x)-f(y)-\langle \nabla f(y), x-y \rangle$.
We name  the function $\phi\colon dom f \times [0,\infty] \rightarrow [0,\infty]$, defined as
$
\phi(x,t) = \inf\{ B_{f}(x,y) : \|x-y\| = t \},
$
the module of total convexity of $f$.
We say that $f$ is totally convex at a point $x \in dom f$ if $\phi(x,t) > 0$ for every $t > 0$. $f$ is totally convex if it is totally convex at every point of its domain.
Question: I'm rather new to this concept, but I'm wondering if it is possible to find (or it is known) a quantitative upper bound to the ratio (or any related ratio) $\frac{\|x-y\|}{\sqrt{B_f(x,y)}}$ in a way that resemble the $\mu$-strongly convex case where one have $\frac{\|x-y\|}{\sqrt{B_f(x,y)}} \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\mu}}$.
Many thanks in advance.

If you know that $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz continuous, then you can get an upper bound. Assume $\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) \|\le L \|x-y\|$ for all $x,y$.
Then using Taylor expansion
$$
B_f(x,y) = \langle \nabla f( y+s(x-y)) - \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle
\le L \|x-y\|^2,
$$
so that
$$
\phi(x,t) \le L t^2.
$$
Clearly, you can work with local Lipschitz continuity. Using integral form of the remainder, one can improve the estimate from $L$ to $\frac L2$.

Thanks, this is going to give a lower bound of $1/\sqrt{L}$ to the ratio $|x-y|/\sqrt{B_f(x,y)}$. I'm more interested into the other direction: for example, if there are other conditions, weaker than strong convexity, leading to an upper bound.
